# Java: A character from a string being added to a constant

Tags: java, char, addition

I encountered an assignment question giving me

```
String test = "problemnumber3";
System.out.println(test.charAt(1));
System.out.println(test.charAt(7));
String piece = test.charAt(13)+4+"7"+test.charAt(13);
System.out.println(piece);
```

and asking what is printed. The answer I came up with looking at the code was that it would print

```
r
n
773
```

but decided to enter it into BlueJ (what we use in class) to double check. The code printed out

```
r
n
5573
```

and I can't figure out where the 55 is coming from. I've checked all the available notes and lecture material I can.
Do the numeric characters from strings add to constants weirdly or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the ASCII representation of the character `'3'`, (automatic conversion) with `4` added to it. `48` is `'0'`, `49` is `'1'`, so `51` is `'3'`. Then the compiler adds `4` to get `55`, then Java's `String` automatically converts the `55` to a `String` representation of `55` when you do `+ "7"`.